# Terraform add role assignment to application registration azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

So I'm creating this application registration in azure but it needs the `Contributor` role. Like this [image]

Now this is done through the Azure portal now i want it through terraform. this is my current code.

```
resource "azuread_application_registration" "app_registration" {
  display_name     = "rcsc-dataplatform"
}
```

Here i create the app registration.

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "service_principal" {
  application_id = azuread_application_registration.app_registration.application_id
}

resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "app_role" {
  app_role_id = azuread_service_principal.service_principal.app_role_ids["Contributor"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.service_principal.object_id
  resource_object_id = azuread_service_principal.service_principal.object_id
}
```

output:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 193, in resource "azuread_service_principal" "service_principal":
│  193:   application_id = azuread_application_registration.app_registration.application_id
│ 
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "application_id".
```

I don't really find anything in the documentation about adding a role to an application registration im using the azuread provider btw.
I look forward to everyones answers, thanks in advance!

Small edit: this role (Contributor) is on resource group level!

Answer (score 0):

As [azuread_application_registration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_registration) indicates, there is no `application_id` argument. Maybe you wanted to use `id` instead?:

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "service_principal" {
  application_id = azuread_application_registration.app_registration.id
}
```