# terraform azuread create app registration with role on resource group level

Tags: terraform, azure-ad-b2c, terraform-provider-azure

So I want to create an App Registration through terraform which is working but I don't know how to give it the "Contributor" role. I think I need to create a service principal as well but documentation about this is not so good imo. This is what I have at the moment

```
resource "azuread_application_registration" "app_registration" {
  display_name     = "rcsc-dataplatform"
}
```

Just to clarify I need to use `application registration` and not `application`.
I look forward to everyones answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you referred --  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_app_role#allowed_member_types

Comment: why posting twice? Isn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77350635/terraform-add-role-assignment-to-application-registration-azure?rq=2 the duplicate of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> terraform azuread create app registration with role on resource group level

`azuread_application_registration` resource type is not supported by the `hashicorp/azuread` provider. To create an `azuread_application_registration`  kindly upgrade the `hashicorp/azuread` provider to new version 3.0.0 using below command.

```
terraform init -upgrade=true
```

To assign an `RBAC` role like **Contributor**, you must create a `service principal`. You can't assign an `RBAC` role to an application created by `azuread_application_registration`. check the [Terraform Doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment#principal_id) for more details.

Here is the Terraform code to create an `azuread_application_registration` and assign the **Contributor** role to the created `service principal`.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "v-venkal-xxxxxxxx"
}

resource "azuread_application_registration" "sample_app" {
  display_name = "venkat-demo-application"
}
resource "azuread_service_principal" "azuread_sp" {
  client_id = azuread_application_registration.sample_app.client_id
  use_existing   = true
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.azuread_sp.object_id
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above `Terraform` code, a `service principal` has been created and assigned the `Contributor` role on the **Resource Group,** as shown below.

[image]